# Consume RESTful WCF service using jQuery $.ajax in MVC 4 application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, wcf

For an MVC 4 application, I am trying to consume RESTful WCF service using jQuery $.ajax function and I am facing issues with it.

Below is my jQuery code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:55205/Services/UserService.svc/GetUserProjects",
    data: '{"gpn": "' + 1 + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

});

Below is my WCF configuration,

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.UserService" behaviorConfiguration="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.UserServiceServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.UserServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.IUserService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.UserServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BugTracker.WcfService.Services.UserServiceServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Below is my WCF code,

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetUserProjects/{gpn}")]
    IList<Project> GetUserProjects(String gpn);
}
```

The issue I am facing is, the WCF service implementation is not hit when I try debugging the code. The service is not hit anytime.

Can anyone suggest if the code I am writing is the correct code or am I missing anything?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you've added a breakpoint and it's not beeing hit?
Is your client still getting a response or an error?

Answer (score 0):

try this change 'GET' to 'POST"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:55205/Services/UserService.svc/GetUserProjects",
    data: '{"gpn": "' + 1 + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
});
```